# How do I derive PersistField for a custom newtype?

Tags: haskell, yesod

This is a Yesod-specific question, but even without knowing Yesod you might be able to help me, it has to do with newtypes.

Say I have the following simplified model in my config/models

```
Value
  userId       UserId
  weight       Weight
  deriving (Show)
```

I will be using both kilograms and pounds in my webapp, but I decided that the DB should store things in kilograms. To get the type-system to protect me from confusing the two, I define the following:

```
newtype Weight = Kilograms Int
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq, PersistField, PersistFieldSql)
```

That compiled fine, but how can I use this from a form?

```
logForm :: UserId -> Form Value
logForm uid = renderDivs $ Value <$>
    pure uid <*>
    areq intField "Weight" Nothing
```

I get the error

```
No instance for (Integral ModelTypes.Weight)
  arising from a use of `intField'
```

I tried deriving `Integral` but then it complains I don't have `Real Weight`. On and on, I end up with:

```
newtype Weight = Grams Int
   deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Enum, Ord, Num, Integral, Real, PersistField, PersistFieldSql)
```

Is this the correct way to do it? It seems like a lot of repetition. What's a better way to do it?

In general, if I have in Haskell a

```
newtype N = T a
```

for a concrete type `a`, how can I have `N` re-derive everything that `a` is in instance of, and also get `N` to derive some other typeclasses (in my example `PersistField` and `PersistFieldSql`). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PersistField isn't the same as a Field.  You want to make a custom field by importing Yesod.Forms.  Here's an example, for a MathJax type ;)

```
newtype MathJax = MathJax { unMathJax :: Markdown }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, PersistField, PersistFieldSql, IsString, Monoid)

unMM :: MathJax -> Text
unMM = unMarkdown . unMathJax

mathJaxField :: (Monad m,  RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m MathJax
mathJaxField = Field
    { fieldParse = parseHelper $ Right . MathJax . Markdown . Text.filter (/= '\r')
    , fieldView  = \theId name attrs val _isReq -> toWidget
      [hamlet|$newline never
        <textarea id="#{theId}" name="#{name}" *{attrs}>#{either id unMM val}
      |]
    , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. Are you sure this is the right approach though, in this case where the underlying type is just a simple Int, and not Markdown (for which you have to write your own fieldParse/fieldView?)

Comment: Yes, you're going to have to write your own field.  The field type brings together a parser (the fieldParse record) and a renderer (the fieldView record).  So you need to parse your URL encoded Int into an Int and then into your newtype.  And similarly, you need to unwrap the newtype.  But that is a "minimal" case.  This isn't derivable, presumably because you might want to have a different way to render or parse for your type.

Comment: This is weird, what I wrote in my question does work – I can normally use an `intField` and it saves to the DB – then when I do get it back from the DB and `show` it I, I do see the field wrapped up in `Kilograms`. On the other hand, changing the newtype to `Kilograms Double`, and then appropriately using a `doubleField`, I keep getting `Couldn't match type 'Double' with 'ModelTypes.Weight'`. How come it worked for `Int` and not `Double`, this is quite peculiar.

Comment: I ended up writing my custom fields just like you showed here, so accepting. Let me know if you figure out a way to use a normal intField for newtypes with an underlying Int without having to resort to making custom new fields and keeping the type safety.